# Change step size for rotation input?

Tags: transforms

I am trying to animate a weapon, and I want to tweak it very slightly. When I click the add or decrease button in the rotation panel under the transforms, it does ALOT more than I want!

[image]

[image]

I have tried to use the Different eulers, but they only add by 1, I want to do very small movements like 0.1 , 0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are in WXYZ rotation mode. You can see in your transformation tab there are four parameters. I honestly have no idea how that rotation mode works, so you can change the tab below those four parameters to "XYZ Euler." It should behave differently now. Hope that helps!

Comment: Ok it helps ill give you a up for that , But i want something very small , like 0.2 , not just 1

Comment: @Knuckles209cp Quaternions basically define an axis around which to rotate and the amount of rotation around it. However, the values are trig values, and not the actual angles. They are in a way a representation of Axis-Angle, but the use of trig values rather than the actual angles makes them easier to use mathematically. The drawback is that it makes them less intuitive. [Using Quaternion to Perform 3D rotations](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/3d/quaternions.html) and [Quaternions and spatial rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) provide some insight.